# how pass file value with this jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, file, file-upload

my code

```
if (submitType == "add") {
    url = "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/packages/add";
} else {
    url = "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/packages/manage/" + slug;
}

$.post(url, $(".package-form").serialize(), function(response) {
    if ($.trim(response) != "done") {
        $(".output").html(response);
    } else {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url().$adminsegment." / packages / "?>";
    }
});
```

I have an input file named **pdfupload** in a form, that value not getting in controller action. anybody knows how to pass that, please help me

Comment: Could you not include the relevant `HTML` to go with your ajax? Also I'm pretty sure `<?php echo base_url().$adminsegment." / packages / "?` could be causing a syntax error as the quotes are close so `/ packages /` isn't part of the string. Would it not be easier to use `window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url().$adminsegment;?>/packages/";`

Comment: form is little big. form class is .package-form,there have <input type =file name=pdfupload>

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `form` tag and retreive the file, on PHP side, in `$_FILES`. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: that also have,then also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: url,
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(success){
                    //success
                }
});
});
```

Dont forget to add enctype in form as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank You so much